# Ubuntu terminal copy line number N from one file to another

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I would like to know is it possible to copy line number 7,8,9 and 17,18 of one text file to another one?

Thanks much in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed` (stream editor) to selectively print lines by number e.g.

```
sed -n '7,9p;17,18p' oldfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

you should **not** rely on the order of the lines on a file, because it might change (if it is a system file, a temp file ecc. and it's updated).
You can use grep or one of its variants, for example rgrep:

```
rgrep WordOrRegularExpressionToMatch "Name_of_the_file"
```

Then, after you see that the lines printer are right, you can use:

```
rgrep WordOrRegularExpressionToMatch "Name_of_the_file" >> "Name_of_the_second_file"
```

It will **append** the lines printed by rgrep to the second file; to overwrite use ">" and not ">>".
If you really want to **extract a precise set of lines** you can use "sed":

```
sed -n -e 7,9p -e 17,18p "Name_of_the_file"
```

(these are 2 separate intervals)

So...

```
sed -n -e 7,9p -e 17,18p "Name_of_the_file" > "Another_file_to_overwrite"
```

(**>> to append**>
Copy & paste the line: it will do the job. :-) 
"**man sed**" will give you more help.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score -2):

If you know how many lines are there in your source file (wc -l) you can do this .. assume 12000 lines and you want lines 2000 - 7000 in your new file (total of 5000 lines).

```
cat myfile | tail -10000 | head -5000 > newfile
```

Read the last 10k lines, then read the 1st 5k lines from that.

Comment: Thank you much for your help!!! It is very interesting approach, thank you.

Comment: You could at least post the link to the original answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259658/copy-paste-part-of-a-file-into-another-file-using-terminal-or-shell/9259792#9259792 .. or do the decent thing and answer it without the use of copy/paste ..